# Streambuilder only fire once

Tags: flutter, stream

I am having a problem where my stream builder is only firing once.

I am trying to configure my bottomNavigationBar to be of a different colour based on the theme selected by the user.

To do this, I have a page whereby the user can decide whether to use the light theme or dark theme. This is saved into the device while shared preferences and then using async, i will stream the current value into my bottomNavigationBar.

The problem occurs when i use a stream builder to create two if statement. Stating that if the value returned from the stream is 0, i will show a "light mode" bottom navigation bar. Else if its 1, i will show a dark theme.

All is well when i run the program for the first time. However upon navigation into the settings page and changing the user preference, the stream builder will not load again. Here are some snapshots of my code

I have tried removing the dispose method whereby the stream will close. However that didn't solve the problem.

The Stream Builder

```
class mainPagev2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _mainPageV2();
  }
}

class _mainPageV2 extends State<mainPagev2>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

//  TabController _tabController;
  StreamController<int> streamController = new StreamController.broadcast();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
//    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: _pageList.length);
    Stream<int> stream = new Stream.fromFuture(readCurrentTheme());
    streamController.addStream(stream);

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
//    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  String currentColor = "#ab3334";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: streamController.stream,
      builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
        print(asyncSnapshot.data.toString() + "WHssssAT IS THIS");
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
          print(asyncSnapshot.error);
          if (asyncSnapshot.data == 0) {
            //Return light themed Container
            currentColor = "#ffffff";
            return ThemeContainer(color: currentColor );
          } else {
            currentColor = "#101424";
            //Return dark themed Container
            return ThemeContainer(color: currentColor );

          }
        } else {
          //return dark themed
          return ThemeContainer(color:currentColor);

        }
      },
    );
//
  }
}
```

Async Code to retrieve the value stored

```
Future<int> readCurrentTheme() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'themeMode';
  final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
  print('read: $value LOOK AT THISSS');
  return value;
}
```

It is expected that the stream builder will fire whenever the value stored is changed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in your code a way to read data from `SharedPreferences` when the value stored is changed. You are effectively reading it once, so the `StreamBuilder` is only firering once. That makes sense.

To be able to do what you want, you have to use something to tell you widget that a state has changed elsewhere in the application. There a multiple ways to achieve this and I won't make the choice for you as it would be opinion based, so you can check thing like [BloC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [ScopedModel](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model), [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)